# How To Insert Data in database with angular2+php backened

Tags: angular

this is my home.component.html where i have put all the HTML

```
<div style="margin-left:25%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
<h2>Add Users</h2>
 <form action="empRegister.php" method="POST" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div>
<label>Full Name</label>
<input type="text" name="emp_name"  ngControl="emp_name">
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

This is my home.component.ts file  and another files will be home.module.ts and routes.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ContactService} from './contact.service';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'home-cmp',
templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
providers : [ContactService]
})

export class HomeComponent {
constructor(private _contactService : ContactService) { }
public message: Insert = {emp_name: ''};
onSubmit() {
  this._contactService.postInsert(this.message).subscribe(
    response => this.handleResponse(response),
    error => this.handleResponse(error)
  );
}
handleResponse(response){
   console.log(`msg is: {response.status}`);
   if(response.status =='success'){
    this.message = {emp_name: ''};
    alert('success');
   }
   if(response.status =='error'){
    alert('error');
   }
  }
}

interface Insert
{
emp_name:string;
}
```

this is contact.service.ts file

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ContactService {
constructor (private _http: Http) {}

private _contactUrl = 
'http://localhost/proj2/src/databaseFiles/empRegister.php';

postInsert(newinsert: Insert): Observable<string>{
let body = `emp_name=${newinsert.emp_name}`;
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-
urlencoded' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this._http.post(this._contactUrl, body, options)
                .map(res =>  <string> res.json())
                .catch(this.handleError)
}

private handleError (error: Response) {
console.error('Error in retrieving : ' + error);
return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
}
```

And for data insertion empRegister.php

```
<?php
require_once 'database_connections.php';
$emp_name = $_POST['emp_name']; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO emp_details (emp_name)
VALUES ('$emp_name')";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
$response_array['status'] = 'success';
echo json_encode($response_array);  
} else {
$response_array['status'] = 'error';
echo json_encode($response_array); 
}
?>
```

so, this is the full process which i have done for data insertion in my mysql database. but data is not inserting in tables

Comment: This is like really broad. What have you tried? You would make http-request and save the data to your backend. Start there :) Tutorial about http: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

Comment: Hello , First try something from your side. You have put the code that is just showing your component not the work you have tried to insert the data. Please try it and put it over here.

Comment: i have uploaded the folder on https://github.com/swapnil1079/angular2_test_project (src/app/dashboard/home) and in  home.component.html i have put the above code. i  have applied injectables but not working . so i have put the fresh code in here to know the full process

Comment: This is not a coding service, you know... ;) You have to show us your effort. As said, gather the data from your form, make a http-request with your data to your backend. Try and do that first, and btw *I have applied injectables but not working* is not really helpful statement... what is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following from your form:

```
action="empRegister.php" method="POST"
```

since you handle the request with your `onSubmit`-function. Then I see some problems in your request. Try and use `URLSearchParams`:

```ts
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

postInsert(newinsert: Insert): Observable<string>{
  let body = new URLSearchParams();
  body.set('emp_name', newinsert.emp_name)
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  return this._http.post(this._contactUrl, body, options)
     .map(res => res.json())
     .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

Comment: when i m  giving the path in form action .. it will directly redirect to that php file (empRegister.php) then data is inserting but its not the correct way so what do i do in  form action??

Comment: remove the form action (and POST), forgot to mention that :)

Comment: So remove the following `action="empRegister.php" method="POST"` You just handle the request when you submit the form with the function `onSubmit()` like you have.

Comment: http://localhost/proj2/src/dashboard/home?emp_name=fhkmm&submit=Submit  this URL is coming on clicking the sbmit .... do i have to make  add extra parameter for submit also?

Comment: Wait... where is this php file located? In your angular project? If so, that won't work :)

Comment: i have to upload it  new files ...just wait

Comment: thier is problem uploading in git repository. basically i have created a new folder inside src folder named  "databaseFiles" and inside this folder i have created two files one is database connection file and other is empRegister.php file. and as u seen i have given path in private _contactUrl = 
'http://localhost/proj2/src/databaseFiles/empRegister.php'; so this is the structure

Comment: That won't work out of the box, you need a server for your backend, using uniform server for example during development

Comment: I have found the problem its because header section if i  use             
 return this._http.post(ths._contactUrl,body,options).map(res => <string> res.json()); instead of console.log(this._http.post(this._contactUrl, body, options).map(res => <string> res.json())); then it wont work  it means header problem what should i do for it?

Comment: I don't understand what you are meaning?